# Hackerrank challenge on how to match a pattern with periods

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to solve the Hackerrank challenge https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/matching-anything-but-new-line. To reiterate, the task is as follows:

[image]

My solution is

```
regex_pattern = r"...\....\....\...."   # Do not delete 'r'.
```

However, I'm failing some test cases:

[image]

I don't see what's wrong with this solution? According to https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html, in the default mode the `.` matches any character except the newline.

Comment: From the discussion page on that challenge: *I eventually got the right answer using anchors (^..$)* - apparently you have to do perfect/exact matches (not allowing anything longer than the pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [UnholySheep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2878796/unholysheep)'s comment, the solution should be

```
regex_pattern = r"^...\....\....\....$" # Do not delete 'r'.
```

so as to not allow anything longer than the given pattern.

[image]

Comment: You could reduce to: `^.{3}(?:\..{3}){3}$`